# Symfony2.8 Could not load type

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create a service on Symfony 2.8 to build a form. But I got this error when I'm trying to reload my page:

[image: CODE ERROR]

Here are the codes used:

[image: services]

SheetType.php (only the part concerning the form) :

```
public function setDefault0ptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'FrontBundle\Entity\Fiche'
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'fiche_form';
}
```

And SheetController.php (same as SheetType, only the part concerning form) :

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{

    $formHandler = $this->get('fiche_handler');

    if ($formHandler->process()){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($formHandler->getForm()->getData());
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('front_fiche_liste'));
    }

    return $this->render('FrontBundle:Fiche:create.html.twig', array('form' => $formHandler->getForm()->createView()));
}
```

Can someone identify the error please?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide all code you add to your question as text, so that those could be copy pasted by users that want to help you. The Controller Code is fined, in this case only the service configuration should be posted as text instead of an image.

Comment: Probably indentation problem in yaml near the line with fiche_type. Should be aligned with other services.

Comment: @ArtemZhuravlev Thanks a lot ! It was that ! "fiche_type" was not aligned with "fiche_form" in the services.yml ;)

Comment: Symfony 2.8 is the bridge between Symfony 2 & Symfony 3 and looking at your code, it contains alot of deprecated code. I'd recommend looking at the upgrade guide to see the deprecations.